# R: Remove character observations in a variable

Tags: r

I have a a variable in a dataframe whose observations are a mix of numeric and character values (due to faulty data entry). How can I subset in only the observations which are numeric? Suppose the values of filename$varname are (1, 2, 1, 5, 3, a, 3, d, 1), I would like subset out "a" and "d" and keep only the rest of the values which are numeric.

Comment: FWIW, sometimes those letter entries are keyed to a special meaning (e.g., "0 due to ...").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a reproducible example it is hard to see what your data actually looks like. For instance, is the column of your data frame a factor or just strings? If it is just strings then Andrie's answer works (just use `as.numeric()`), and if the data is a factor you first need to convert that to strings with `as.character(x)`:

```
as.numeric(as.character(filename$varname))
```

You will get some `NA`s but that is absolutely fine as those values are indeed missing.

EDIT: To clarify abit more. You have a data frame, so you don't want to take values out of the data frame as then it wouldn't be a dataframe anymore (equal rows). You want to correctly assign `NA` for missing values instead as most statistical functions in R can handle them.

Comment: Thanks, Sacha. Is there any way to convert multiple variables (var1, var2, var3, etc.) this way in one shot instead of applying this routine for all of them one by one?

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the fact that `as.numeric` will convert character strings to `NA` whilst keeping numeric data:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 1, 5, 3, "a", 3, "d", 1)
as.numeric(x)

[1]  1  2  1  5  3 NA  3 NA  1
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Now use `is.na` to test for `NA` values and exclude these using vector subsetting:

```
y <- as.numeric(x)
y[!is.na(y)]
[1] 1 2 1 5 3 3 1
```