# Remove records starting a character (Vxxx) to enable floor() command in R

Tags: r, character, floor

I'm working with emergency room ICD-9 code data (health diagnoses), which are three-digit codes with up to 2 decimals after (examples: 499, 499.1, 499.51, etc). Some special codes have the letter "V" instead of a first digit, such as "V10.46".

Every emergency room visit (row) can have up to 11 diagnoses codes (columns), so I used reshape() to change the dataset to long format.  Now I want to use floor() to remove those decimal points. But R can't floor something with a character!  I get this error: *Error in Math.factor(dtl$diag) : floor not meaningful for factors*

This post had some relevance but I'm wondering if there's a better way?  [R: Remove character observations in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607985/r-remove-character-observations-in-a-variable)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building off @Vincent Zoonekynd's excellent answer, If the aim was to use `floor` on the data, you can just strip the "V" and call `floor` on the rest:

```
x <- c("499", "499.1", "499.51", "V10.46")
# replace all occurences of "V" with nothing ("") in x:
x.stripped <- gsub("V", "", x) 
# convert to numeric so we can use floor():
x.floor <- floor(as.numeric(x.stripped))
```

Based off your error message, "not meaningful for factors", that column of your data has been read in as strings (because of the "V" in some of the rows), and the default behaviour of R is to convert string columns into factors (like categories).

If you get an error about `gsub` not working on factors, you need to convert your column to strings first:

```
mydf$columname <- as.character(mydf$columnname)
```

And then you can proceed as before.

Comment: Hi mathematical.coffee.  I like this idea, but the problem is that if you remove the "V" and floor then the code becomes indistinguishable from the pre-existing two-digit codes that share the same number. (For example, "V10.46" would become the same as all codes "10.x" that all become "10"). I tried to replace the V with a 0, but that still gets merged with the existing codes. Can you replace the "V" with multiple digits?

Comment: Hmm, if you want to keep the preceding V, use @VincentZoonekynd's answer.

Comment: I replaced the "V" with "919"- it's different enough from any of the codes but still fulfills the numeric format requirement!

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regular expression to remove the dot and everything after.

```
x <- c("499", "499.1", "499.51", "V10.46")
gsub("\\..*", "", x)
# Output:
# [1] "499" "499" "499" "V10"
```

Comment: I'm a novice- what does "\\..*" refer to? and ""?

Comment: It's a regular expression -- it means "replace a literal . (which is '\.' in regex, and backslashes need to be escaped in R, hence '\\.') followed by anything (the `.*`) by nothing (`""`)". So it removes anything after and including a decimal point, which simulates `floor`. Although I think you also wanted to strip the first "V" right? Look at `?gsub` and see if you can do something similar to remove the "V" (it will be easier than the gsub in this answer). Then, you can use `as.numeric` to convert the strings to numbers.

Comment: Can this gsub expression be used within calling a certain column? In your example, if i wanted to do this to the values in column 4 i would do this: gsub("\\..*", "", x$4)?

Comment: almost: `x[[4]] <- gsub("\\..*","",x[[4]])`

Comment: Okay but that assigns column 4- i want to REPLACE all the values in column 4 with the new values that don't have decimals. The column i'm interested in is called "diag". Here's my try: dtlong$diag = gsub("\\..*", "", dtlong$diag)    ?  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For first three letters you can use substring function.

```
icd9 <- factor(c("499", "499.1", "499.51", "V10.46"))
substr(as.character(icd9),1,3)# as.character is used 
                              # because icd9 is factor in your data
```

Output

```
[1] "499" "499" "499" "V10"
```